# Can not install Docear on ubuntu18.04

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install [Docear](http://www.docear.org/) on ubuntu 18.04, but only result in opening the Docear window and can not finish the installation. Is there any way to finish the installation?

Screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iugt7.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Er9.png).

Comment: Which version of Docear? Which `java -version`? Take a look to [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can clone my own docear repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/fmuni/docear). It should work out of the box on Ubuntu since it comes with the right java library (and it does not require to set additional environment variables).

Unfortunately, it seems like the project is not developed anymore and the software can only be kept up-to-date by the opensource community.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. I'm on a linux mint 20 machine

Answer (score 1):

The default Java Runtime Environment in my 18.10 (openjdk-11-jre) seems to be incompatible with Docear (Docear has not been updated since 2015, unfortunately). I've had success running it with JRE version 8, which is the version java for which it was developed. Remove default-jre and install openjdk-8-jre

[java](/questions/tagged/java) [jre](/questions/tagged/jre)

Answer (score 0):

Download java8 from Oracle (for instance, here: https://www.java.com/fr/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml). From hereon I suppose you have followed their instructions and that it is installed in `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_xyz`. You may have done this as such:

```bsh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/java
cd $_
sudo tar zxvf <path/to/tar-file>
```

Now open your `.bashrc` and add this at the bottom

```bsh
# Docear needs java1.8 which is checked through the variable JAVACMD
JAVACMD=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_xyz/bin/java
FREEPLANE_BASE_DIR=<path/to/docear/directory> # seems to be needed from second use on, not sure why
```

to make sur this is done right, we'll source the bashrc and test in the command line, so open up a terminal

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc
echo $JAVACMD
```

this should return `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_xyz/bin/java`

now launch Docear from the command line in the directory of the extracted zip file as

```bsh
. docear.sh
```

all should be fine and you're ready to go (without replacing your current version of java which may be needed for other applications/software).